# Apply discount on Shipping Price - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

I searched a lot and i didn't find a way to to it.
I need to create a coupon code that when it's applied gives a 100% discount based on Shipping Price selected.

I don't want to change the price of the shipping to $0.   I want to give a discount in the same price of selected shipping method.

**Example of Shopping Cart:**

```
Products = $100
Shipping = $15
Discount (COUPON FREESHIPPING) = -$15

Final Price = $100
```

That way i can control how much the company spends with free shipping.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I figered out a way to do it.

I did this recently with a sort of hackish use of the sales rule admin panel.

In your rule, under 'actions', in the panel 'Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions', create a condition that can never actually occur. I used "sub total" == '0'. As long as you have selected 'Apply to Shipping Amount', it will take the discount only from the shipping costs. It will not match any items in the cart, though.